# clean url redirection for my website users profile page

Tags: mod-rewrite

users profile page URL in my website is **example.com/user/profile.php?user=dernier**.
and I need to mod-rewrite the URL in this form **example.com/dernier**. can some one guide me how to do it.. I am new to coding.
where should i add .htaccess file? in root folder or user folder?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can both place the mod_rewrite directives in the root folder, user folder, or the httpd.conf or virtualhost file.  The directives will be slightly differently in each case:

If placed in the .htaccess in the root folder, the mod_rewrite will look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^user/profile.php /%1? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

If placed in the user folder, the mod rewrite will look different:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^profile.php /%1? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

In these cases, I'm assuming you want to have a permanent redirect.  Feel free to change to a [L,R]  for a non-permanent redirect if that's what you want.

Comment: i added your code .its not working. when i go to example.com/dernier ,it shows 404 error.but it should show  the example.com/user/profile.php?user=dernier result.